# How to store Searched URL in Data Structure using Java Script

Tags: javascript, url, request, window, storage

I need to create URL Blocking & storage (Local Storage ) add-on using Javascript.

I need to block some websites & storage also, that means using any Data Structure   I need to store Some of website Names , when ever user enter website name if it exist in data structure  we need to block that one ,if it is not exist in data structure storage we need to store the website name into data structure.

if url exist in data structure
block url
else
store the url in data structure

I'm already tried widows variable , but due to lack of my knowledge in JS Im unable to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do that using local storage as Local Storage entries have a scope limited to the site in which they were created. Eg: youtube.com 's Local Storage can't be accessed in google.com. So the Local Storage in each application (website) is keep private to itself and you can't create one which can be active/accessed when you go to other sites. This is so due to Security concerns.